# Change date format in cck field

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8 i would like to change the date format in cck date field of a custom content type . For example i would like to have french format d/m/Y . How can i do this ? I've try this code that i have found here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2646454 to a custom module but that 's  not working , nothing change in my field:

```
function mymodule_element_info_alter(array &$types) {

// Set defaults for datetime fields.

$types['datetime']['#process'][] = '_set_datetime_defaults';

}

/**

* Set defaults for datetime fields.

*/

function _set_datetime_defaults($element) {

$element['date']['#attributes']['data-drupal-date-format'] = ['d/m/Y'];

$element['date']['#date_date_format'] = 'd/m/Y';

$element['date']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = ["DD-MM-YYY"];

$element['time']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = ["HH:MM:SS"];

return $element;

}
```

Thanks for your help

Edit : 
In admin/config/regional/date-time , i've create my custom date format but i'm not able to see it in manage form display . You can check attached

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use the formats available at `/admin/config/regional/date-time`?

Comment: I think this is in regards to forms and not displays.

Comment: Go one more tab over to Manage Display.

Comment: Yes in manage display there is a option to change date format but i need this option to in manage form display tab to be able to change date format when i create or edit a node